# Query that combines three tables to show total counts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't seem to wrap my mind around getting this query right. I have three tables and want to combine them to show how many tickets are left at each location. I am running SQL Server 2008 R2.

Location Table

```
LocationId | LocationName
1          | Location1 
2          | Location2
3          | Location3
```

Tickets Per Location Table

```
TicketId | LocationId | EventId | Amount
1        | 1          | 4       | 25
1        | 2          | 4       | 50
1        | 3          | 4       | 100
```

Purchased Tickets Table

```
AttendeeId | EventId | TicketId | LocationId | Amount | EmployeeId
1          | 4       | 1        | 1          | 5      | 101
2          | 4       | 1        | 1          | 10     | 102
3          | 4       | 1        | 2          | 2      | 103
4          | 4       | 1        | 2          | 4      | 103
```

I want the query to display the three tables like this:

```
LocationName | Starting | Sold | Remaining
Location1    | 25       | 15   | 10
Location2    | 50       | 6    | 44
Location3    | 100      | 0    | 0
```

This is the query I had been playing with but it only shows me locations with tickets that have been sold, I need it to show me all locations even if they don't have tickets sold.

```
SELECT L.LocationName, T.Amount as Starting, COALESCE(SUM(P.Amount),0) as Sold, COALESCE((T.Amount - SUM(P.Amount)),0) as Remaining
FROM TicketsPerLocation T
LEFT JOIN Locations L
ON T.LocationId = L.LocationId
LEFT JOIN PurchasedTickets P
ON T.LocationId = P.LocationId 
WHERE T.TicketId = 1 AND T.EventId = 4 AND P.TicketId = 1
GROUP BY L.Name, T.Amount, T.TicketId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to move your tables around a little bit..

```
SELECT  l.LocationName,
        tpl.Amount,
        COALESCE(SUM(pt.Amount),0) Sold,
        tpl.Amount - COALESCE(SUM(pt.Amount),0) Remaining
FROM    Locations l
        INNER JOIN TicketsPerLocation tpl ON l.LocationID = tpl.LocationID
        LEFT JOIN PurchasedTickets pt ON tpl.TicketID = pt.TicketID 
            AND tpl.LocationID = pt.LocationID 
            AND tpl.EventID = pt.EventID
WHERE   tpl.TicketID = 1 AND tpl.EventID = 4
GROUP BY l.LocationName, 
        tpl.Amount
```

plus your where statement had `P.TicketId = 1` which makes that a INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN.. so remove that.

when you join to `PurchasedTickets`, make sure it's on all of the fields that are related to `TicketsPerLocation` and not just Location

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8bf66/2)

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few problems in your query. See if fixing these solves it:

1. Since you want all locations, you should start with that table before the LEFT JOIN, not after it.
2. The Purchased Tickets table is an outer join, but you have it in your where clause. That's always a bad combination because those two things contradict each other. I would move that requirement to the ON clause.

```
    SELECT L.LocationName
        ,T.Amount AS Starting
        ,COALESCE(SUM(P.Amount), 0) AS Sold
        ,COALESCE((T.Amount - SUM(P.Amount)), 0) AS Remaining
    FROM Locations L
    LEFT JOIN TicketsPerLocation T ON T.LocationId = L.LocationId
    LEFT JOIN PurchasedTickets P ON T.LocationId = P.LocationId
        AND P.TicketId = 1
    WHERE T.TicketId = 1
        AND T.EventId = 4
    GROUP BY L.NAME
        ,T.Amount
        ,T.TicketId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT L.LocationName, T.Amount as Starting, ISNULL(p.SumAmt,0) As Sold, T.Amount - ISNULL(p.SumAmt,0) AS Remaining
FROM Locations L
LEFT JOIN TicketsPerLocation T
  ON T.LocationId = L.LocationId AND T.TicketId = 1 AND T.EventId = 4 
LEFT JOIN 
   ( SELECT [EventId], [TicketId], [LocationId], SUM(Amount) AS SumAmt 
     FROM PurchasedTickets
     GROUP BY [EventId], [TicketId], [LocationId]
    ) p
    ON T.LocationId = P.LocationId
    AND P.TicketId = T.TicketId AND P.EventId = T.EventId
 ORDER BY L.LocationName
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a0ac4/7)